# How to install gem from private GitHub repo using 'gem install' command

Tags: git, github, rubygems

How do I install a gem locally that is hosted in a private repo on GitHub?

In particular, we are installing it via a `gem install` command rather than using in Bundler since it is a command line tool.

I tried doing this:

```
gem install githubname-repo -s https://github.com/githubname/repo.git
```

And this:

```
gem install repo -s https://github.com/githubname/repo.git
```

Without success... I just get a 404 message with both:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'githubname-repo' (>= 0), here is why:
      Unable to download data from https://github.com/githubname/repo.git/ - bad response Not Found 404 (https://github.com/githubname/repo.git/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In HTTPS, the basic authentication params in URL need to be set like

```
https://user:password@github.com/username/repo.git
```

I think this may work for rubygems.

#### Update

Your problem is different, the -s flag indicate a gem server, so if you like to distribute and install a private gem, you have 3 options

1. Clone the private repo and build the sources wit gem build ..
2. Install via bundler, you can set the github repo and set the url like my first answer.
3. Use a private gem server like https://gemfury.com/l/gem-server or setup your own server http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-server

Comment: Unfortunately, no dice. Here is what I see: $ gem install repo -s https://username:password@github.com/username/repo
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'repo' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://username:password@github.com/username/repo/ - bad response Not Found 404 (https://username:password@github.com/username/repo/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: ...

Comment: @ChrisButler I update the answer, please review once again !!